# How can I define this relationship: User belongsToMany Companies and User hasMany Roles/Company in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm creating a website where a User can login, select a Company and after selection has assigned Roles for that company. These Roles can be different for each company.

I've tried hasMany and polymorphic releationships with tables for users, companies and roles but can't get it to work.

```
//In the Role model:    
public function company()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Comp', 'userroles');
}
public function users()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'userroles');
}
```

I would like a list of all the Roles/User for the selected Company, a list of Users/Companies for each Role and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//In the Company model:    
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

//In the User model:
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comp');
}
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Comp');
}

//In the Role model:
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Then, you can simply access the users in a company like `{{$company->users}}`, `{{$user->company}}`, `{{$user->role}}` or may be like `{{$role->users}}`

Comment: Thanks Subham, but a user can have many roles and I don't  understand why the role has one company because a role can be used by many users in different companies.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. It should return `Role` model in `role()` relationship. Also, change the hasOne to hasMany. Like `hasMany('App\Role')`. That's how, a user have many roles.